# Do these Sony bodies have integrated AF motors?

Tags: autofocus, sony, sony-alpha, focus-motor, e-mount

I'm on the lookout for a new camera body and new lenses. I have come down to these 3 Sony cameras; Sony A6300, Sony A7 and Sony A7II. My question is, do these cameras have an itegrated AF motor inside the body? Or do I need to get lenses with AF motors? And also, do all E and FE lenses have AF motors? If not, which ones do in the sub $1000 price range?

Comment: On a (somewhat relevant) point of order, the models you refer to are actually called _α6300_, _α7_ and _α7 II_ (note: 'α' not 'A')

Answer (score 3):

Sony has made this *super* confusing by using *alpha* (α) —which is commonly rendered "A" — in the names of these *E*-mount cameras. (Thanks, Sony!)  The current scheme seems to be: α followed by two digits = A-mount; all others (one digit, four digits, one digit and some letters, whatever) are E-mount. In addition to their "common names", these cameras also have *model numbers* which start with "ILCE", where the E stands for E-mount (and ILCA for A-mount cameras). The ones you list are ILCE-6300, ILCE-7, and ILCE-7M2, respectively.

All E-mount lenses have their own motors, so do not need a "screw-drive" motor in the body.

Some A-mount lenses have motors, but older ones do not. (I'm 90% sure that all Sony A-mount lenses with focus motors are labeled either SSM or SAM — if the description is missing this, look more closely.)

The E-mount bodies (like the ones you've listed) do not have in-body motors, but if you want to use A-mount lenses that require it, the [Sony  LA-EA4](http://www.sony.com/electronics/converters-mount-adapters/la-ea4) adapter includes one of its own.

If you use native E-mount lenses — just as if you are a Nikon users with newer Nikon-mount lenses, or a Canon EOS user using native EOS lenses — this is a non-issue.

Comment: I will challenge this and say that _Sony_ has not made this super confusing, but rather others have (IMO), by not following Sony's lead. That is, yes, Sony uses Alpha to refer to its interchangeable lens cameras, both A and E mount, but Sony (Japan) never uses uppercase Alpha ('Α') for this, only lowercase Alpha ('α'). It is others' use of Latin letter 'A' in place of the Alpha symbol that leads to confusion (probably because it's usually a lot easier to type Latin 'A' than Greek 'α'). It is correct though that Latin letters 'A' and 'E' are used in product codes...but not in product _names_